# piping to groovy script input

Tags: groovy, pipe

I am writing a groovy script that takes args from line or from pipe.

First of all, accessing pipe or args is different:

- you access args from `args` variable
- you access pipe through `System.in.text`

so everything is working fine in my script

BUT

when i run the script remotely (ie `groovy http://mysite.com/myscript.groovy`), SOMETIMES piping is not working, ie nothing in the pipe (System.in.text is empty), but sometimes it works.

I managed to fix this delaying reading `System.in` by 300ms (ie `sleep 300` command)

I wonder if i miss something in reading pipe or should i report a bug somehow

Example script: https://github.com/fix/groovy-spark/blob/master/Spark.groovy

Comment: Have you tried using `System.in.eachLine()`?

Comment: yes same issue actually, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it like so:

```
BufferedReader Sin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
```

... from the Java API docs.

Then proceed as usual with `Sin.text`

Comment: unfortunately it is hanging as well when there is nothing in the pipe

Comment: Check if `Sin.ready()` is true. While it is, keep reading lines. Finish looping when it's false. I created an example here for my own template usage here: https://github.com/sarnobat/getopts

Answer (score 0):

```
def input = System.in.newReader().readLine()
```